# What happens if a thread calls release() before acquire() in std::counting_semaphore

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

What happens if a thread calls release() before acquire() in std::counting_semaphore.
Does the compiler throw error?

Tried nothing. Just wanted to know what happens in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

One common metaphor for a counting semaphore is to think of it as a bag of "permits," where a "permit" represents permission to do some thing.

"Release" means, that the caller is giving up a permit--returning it to the bag, and "acquire" means taking a permit from the bag. "Release" therefore makes the count go up. "Acquire" makes the count go down. But since the bag is not allowed to hold a negative number of permits, performing "acquire" on an empty bag will make the caller wait until some other thread "releases" a permit that the acquire operation can then take.

So, to answer your question. "Release" simply increments the count. It adds a permit to the bag. It's not an error. Your code can release as many permits as you like. You may choose to have your own code limit the number of permits that may be released to the semaphore, but the semaphore itself does not enforce any limit.